# FtpWebRequest locks up after two requests only when using the BeginGetResponse/EndGetResponse pair

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, webrequest, ftpwebrequest

To put things into context, imagine a program that retrieves the size of a file from an FTP server using FtpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(). If it fails to get the file size due to some connection error, it tries again after some time. It also allows the user to cancel the whole operation.

The problem occurs after retrying a specific amount of times: **in case FtpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse() fails to connect more than ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit times on the same endpoint, subsequent callbacks won't be called, and wait handles will block indefinitely.**

Using [TCPView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx), one may see that no new connection attempt is made after the first ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit (failed) connection attempts.

Let me demonstrate the problem with some contrived examples.

Assuming,

- .NET 4.6
- ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit == 2
- 192.168.1.2 is **not** the IP address of the machine running the examples.
- Either 192.168.1.2 is not reachable or it has no service running at port 21.

The synchronous version,

```
static void Main(string[] args){

    var uri = new Uri("ftp://192.168.1.2/test.txt");

    for (var z = 0; z < ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit + 1; z += 1){

        try {

            var request = (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;

            using (var response = request.GetResponse())

                Console.WriteLine(response.ContentLength);

        } catch (WebException ex){

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Status);

        }

    }

}
```

terminates with console output,

```
ConnectFailure
ConnectFailure
ConnectFailure
```

while,

```
static void Main(string[] args){

    var uri = new Uri("ftp://192.168.1.2/test.txt");

    for (var z = 0; z < ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit + 1; z += 1){

        var request = (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;

        request.BeginGetResponse(PrintFileSizeCallback, request);

    }

    Console.ReadKey(false);

}

static void PrintFileSizeCallback(IAsyncResult ar){

    try {

        using (var response = ((FtpWebRequest) ar.AsyncState).EndGetResponse(ar))

            Console.WriteLine(response.ContentLength);

    } catch (WebException ex){

        Console.WriteLine(ex.Status);
    }

}
```

will print,

```
ConnectFailure
ConnectFailure
```

and the third callback will never take place.

Even waiting on the async method to complete makes no difference:

```
static void Main(string[] args){

    var uri = new Uri("ftp://192.168.1.2/test.txt");

    for (var z = 0; z < ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit + 1; z += 1){

        try {

            var request = (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;

            var responseAsyncResult = request.BeginGetResponse(null, null);

            using (var response = request.EndGetResponse(responseAsyncResult))

                Console.WriteLine(response.ContentLength);

        } catch (WebException ex){

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Status);

        }

    }

}
```

will output,

```
ConnectFailure
ConnectFailure
```

and hang.

Identical behaviour is observed if awaiting FtpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync().

Now for the funny part: If 192.168.1.2 **is** the IP address of the machine that runs any of the previous examples, or 192.168.1.2 is replaced by a loopback address, the problem vanishes.

Ok, let's make some minor modifications to the previous example:

```
static void Main(string[] args){

    var uri = new Uri("ftp://192.168.1.2/test.txt");

    for (var z = 0; z < ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit + 1; z += 1){

        try {

            var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);

            var responseAsyncResult = request.BeginGetResponse(null, null);

            using (var response = request.EndGetResponse(responseAsyncResult))

                Console.WriteLine(response.ContentLength);

        } catch (WebException ex){

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Status);

        }

    }

}
```

Again, it'll fail like the other ones did, unless the address is local/loopback.

But if the uri scheme is changed to http, all is well...

So, is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What happens if you try the same thing as your 2nd to last test but get rid of the `responseAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();` line? If you do `request.EndGetResponse(responseAsyncResult)` is should block till the request is complete.

Comment: @scott Indeed ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.endgetresponse(v=vs.110).aspx)). I'll remove that line to simplify the code. But still, it never completes.